# Our 4-month-old child is allergic to milk products. Can we start giving him solid foods?

Tags: infant, feeding, allergies

My 4-month-old son is allergic to milk products and as per pediatrician's advice we're giving him formula milk Zerolac – and no breastmilk.

Can someone advise whether we can start giving him the solid foods from now on? If yes, please suggest some healthy food items that we can offer.

Comment: If he has allergies, it's best to ask your pediatrician for advice. That's what they are there for - helping you to make and keep your child healthy.

Comment: @CVers, I don't think this is in the realm of medical advice.  The OP is not asking to contradict the pediatrician; simply asking if it's appropriate to start feeding a 4 month old solid foods.  That's solidly in the realm of questions we answer here.  While I agree that the pediatrician should be part of the answer, one of the reasons people post here is to find out more information so they can have an informed discussion with their pediatrician about topics like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the advice of our pediatrician, we started giving our kids solid foods after 6 months. When she told us how to do this, she indicated that the quantity of solid foods wasn't particularly important, because the baby was still getting its primary nutritional needs met by the breast milk (in your case, formula). Our kids weaned on their own anywhere between 9 months and more than a year and a half, depending on their preferences.

First, I recommend asking your pediatrician your questions, as sh/e will be able to provide you advice based on your child's medical history and needs. It sounds like your child's needs are different than the average child that is the same age, so **your child's doctor is the best place to get definitive advice**.

When you decide to start on solid foods, our doctor recommended that we start with single-grain cereal to start with. We started with rice cereal. We then added baby food (either commercial, or mashed up on our own) **one flavor at a time**. This is especially important if you are concerned your baby may be affected by allergies. If you see an allergic reaction, you want to know what caused it. That means you should only introduce one new food every couple of days.

Finally, my last bit of advice is that if your child rejects a particular type of food, don't consider it a lost cause. You may need to introduce a food to your child 10 or more times before they decide they like it. Persistence is a virtue.

Comment: thank you for your comments, since my son is just taking Soy Protein Formula milk, our PDs suggeted to go with Rice Cereal alone for next one month and based upon his feedback will find other solid foods..

Comment: Great! When we were ready to introduce solid foods, we had luck with sweet potatoes and other similar one-ingredient veggies. Often we cooked them ourselves and mashed them in a baby food grinder (much cheaper than purchased baby food). We tried to avoid fruits early on b/c once our kids had fruit, they preferred that to the veggies. Good luck!

Comment: The single grain cereal recommendation is no longer one that the AAP promotes or supports.  There's no particular reason to feed single grain cereals over single vegetables or anything else, and in the case of rice cereal concerns exist related to arsenic levels that rice isn't necessarily a great idea early on.  (And with sweet potatoes and carrots, be aware of nitrate levels; if you are serving your own home-made vegetables, certain vegetables should also be avoided early on.)

Answer (score 2):

The earliest recommended age for weaning is 4 months, and as you cannot feed him milk, there is no reason not to start on solid foods.

Mashed up, or puréed fruits or vegetables - banana, apple, pear, carrot, potato, parsnip etc. These are very simple first foods, and while they are messy, babies rapidly learn how to eat them.

Once they are happily eating these, you can add meat, fish, pasta etc.

You can get a very good idea of the kinds of foods that are suitable by looking at the jars of baby food you see in shops. Lots of soft purées, tiny pieces of soft pasta, rice/wheat baby cereals etc.

Comment: There's also rice/wheat baby cereals available, which can be mixed with formula.

Comment: Rory, Erica - thank you for your advice! I will try with first solid food of Apple, Banana and Rice and let know how my son taking in.. :)

Comment: @P.K.S, not *and*, especially with allergic babies. Start with *one* fruit for a week and see how he reacts. If everything is fine, introduce the next food in the same way and so on.

Comment: Stephie, sure! many thanks for your suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

We started with solids with our toddler at 6 months, until then 100% breastfeeding and at that point forward whenever it felt right. This was inspired by "baby-led weaning" which I think is basically offering the kid everything you're eating--slices of avocado, pieces of fish, and cheese. Stuff he wouldn't choke.